# A problem on limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is it correct  that $$\lim_{n->\infty}n!^{1/n}=\infty?$$ how to prove it using basic properties of sequence?

Comment: In fact the limit is $\infty$; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: Why do you think it would go to zero? Did you try some numbers?

Answer (score 7):

**Elementary proof (without Stirling)**

In $n! = n\times (n-1) \times (n-2)\dots 2\times 1$, at least $\dfrac{n}{2}$ of the terms are $\geq \dfrac{n}{2}$, so $n! \geq \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^\frac{n}{2}$.

This shows that
$$n!^\frac{1}{n} \geq \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another elementary proof:  Split the sequence into pairs, 1 and $n$, 2 and $n-1$ and so on.  The product of any pair is at least $n$, so the $n^{th}$ root of $n!$ is at least $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have for large $n$ that $$n!\sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$$ thus $$(n!)^\frac{1}{n} \sim \frac{n}{e}\left(2\pi n\right)^{\frac{2}{n}}.$$ Considering the two factors separately $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2\pi n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$$ and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{e} = \infty$$
Thus the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is $\infty$ not zero.

Comment: Stirling's approximation is a pretty big hammer to use here, but on the other hand maybe that's a good thing.

Comment: It's the first thing that popped into my head; though I suppose technically it doesn't answer the question because it uses more than "basic properties of the sequence".

Comment: One nice thing about Stirling's approximation is that it squashes so many problems so very flat with such little effort. Everyone should have it in their toolbox, even if they don't plan to use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Dan's answer is correct, but you could also use the more general lemma:

**Lemma:** if $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is a *positive* sequence, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=A\implies \begin{cases}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot a_2\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n}=A\\{}\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}n=A\end{cases}$$

BTW, $\;A\;$ above can be finite *or not*.